# Adding Java .properties files to Pootle

Tags: java, properties, internationalization, translation, pootle

I am attempting to add .properties files to Pootle and am trying to get it to recognize the English properties file as the template file. For some reason Pootle is failing to do this and I am not sure why. I can successfully add all of my properties files in whatever languages I want to Pootle, but then when I try to start translating Pootle fails to match the keys and show the English template strings in the translation interface. Just wondering if anyone else has come across this or has any ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured this out on my own already. In case anyone else comes across this and still needs an answer, you simply have to change Project Tree Style to "GNU style: files named by language code" under the Administration/Projects tabs.

Comment: Can you provide more detail of the correct settings and structure? I'm having issues with the same thing, but have already set the project to GNU style.